# Uninitialized constant System (NameError) in Selenium with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am learning automation and have no prior programming knowledge. I am trying to learn Selenium with ruby: I am having issues with launching the firefox browser.What am i doing wrong?
My code is

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://facebook.com"
puts"facebook is loaded in FF browser"
```

I am getting the following error:

> 3:in '':uninitialized constant System (NameError)
>   Did you mean? SysytemExit

Comment: Quick comment on question formatting... make sure you take a look at the formatting help. If you add 4 spaces at the start of a line, it will format that line as code. If you add a > at the start of a line, it colorizes it in yellow. I've made these changes to your question... these are a couple of the formatting options that are expected in questions to make them easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a friendly suggestion. Learn the basics of ruby and debugging before you try learning selenium. Trying to learn selenium and ruby at the same time is like trying to do gymnastics and learning how to walk. You have to learn how to walk before you can do gymnastics.

Comment: You are mixing ruby and java code, and ruby is (correctly) throwing an error when you call `System` because that's a java class.  I agree with @testerjoe: you should get comfortable with ruby and then try to learn selenium.  Or--if you can handle some frustration--work through the documentation at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings and turn to google when you get stuck.

Comment: @orde - please consider putting your comment as an answer.

Comment: What they said.  See http://seleniumtutorials.com/2013/09/25/selenium/ruby-selenium-webdriver-tutorial-part-1-writing-our-first-test/